# Manually config via ADB delay between refresh rate change

Tags: android, dynamic, refresh, rate, surfaceflinger

My Asus Zenfone 8 supports dynamic refresh rate.

But the delay between switching both refresh rate too long, it tooks about 2-3 seconds.
Can anybody points me how to quicken the delay to about 1 second between refresh rate change?

I set my refresh rate to 120hz
and manually set via adb peak_refresh_rate 120
and min_refresh_rate 60.

i can't find anything from adb on time between changes.